# Affine plane of order 4?

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, affine-geometry

I cannot seem to construct an affine plane of order 4. I have the construction for order 3- but cannot seem to come up with or find the construction for 4 anywhere. Could someone show me a picture of one, preferably with parallel lines indicated?

Answer (score 1):

An example is given [here](http://www.york.cuny.edu/~malk/mycourses/math244/finite-plane-examples.html), but without any motivation. You could probably try looking at $F\times F$, where $F$ is the field of 4 elements.

EDIT: Here's another way. [Here](http://www.maa.org/editorial/mathgames/mathgames_05_30_06.html) is a drawing of an order 4 projective plane. Remove any one line, and the five points on that line, and what's left is an affine plane of order 4.

Comment: Wouldn't F need to have 2 elements for the plane to have order 4? (What I am asking is, what is the order? :) )

Comment: Could you draw a picture for the plane described? Some of lines are definitely incorrect. For instance I think 1,5,9,14 is definitely 1,5,9,13.

Comment: @Mariano, in this context, "order" means the number of points on a line.

Comment: @Danielle, I don't vouch for the example at the link, and if you have found a mistake there, +1 for you. Have you thought about the suggestion to use that finite field?

Comment: Yes, and I did figure that out. Thanks, Gerry.

Comment: Doesn't removing a line from an order four projective plane give us an order 3 affine plane?

Comment: @Thomas, the projective plane of order 4 has 21 points on 21 lines, 5 points on each line, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_plane#Finite_projective_planes – the affine plane of order 4 has 16 points, 4 on each line, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_plane_(incidence_geometry)#Finite_affine_planes – so removing a line from an order 4 projective plane leaves an order 4 affine plane.