# Dobble Algorithm for three or more matches.

Tags: combinatorics, card-games

I've played Dobble and asked myself it is possible to have instead of pairs, $n$ cards having one symbol in common, for example for $n=3$ if you take any three cards they only have one symbol in common. I've found two trivial solutions ; the first with only a single symbol shared by all cards, and the second one is every unique combination of $n$ cards has its own unique symbol.

Dobble is a game with 55 Cards, any two cards of the 55 Cards only share one symbol.

Comment: There are $\binom n3$ subsets of size $3$, so for each of those create a special symbol and distribute to those people (and only those people).  this generalizes to subsets of size $k$ in the obvious way.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Shouldn't you describe Dobble. People may not know about it ? At least I don't !

Comment: @true blue anil https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobble This is a fascinating game to play with kids in particular. Fascinating also by the fact that it is based on finite projective planes.

Comment: Obligatory youtube link to Matt Parker's (*stand-up maths*) [video about the maths of dobble](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTDKqW_GLkw).  The most surprising thing to me was that the standard dobble printing left out two additional possible cards for some unknown reason.

Answer (score 2):

Let us consider the case of $6$ cards meeting the constraint "any group of 3 cards has a single common symbol" ; an elementary solution exists which can be described by the following boolean array where the $6$ cards are represented by the lines and the $20 = \binom{6}{3}$ symbols are represented by the columns :

$$\begin{matrix}
1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&0&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&0&1&1&1&0&0&0&1&1&1&0&0&0&1&1&1&0\\
0&1&0&0&1&0&0&1&1&0&1&0&0&1&1&0&1&1&0&1\\
0&0&1&0&0&1&0&1&0&1&0&1&0&1&0&1&1&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&1&0&0&1&0&1&1&0&0&1&0&1&1&0&1&1&1\end{matrix}$$
The problem is that this "brute-force" solution it necessitates already 20 symbols for only 6 cards ; with 10 cards, one would have to use $\binom{10}{3}=120$, etc. !

But there is a way to "narrow" the number of symbols. See the second array in the sequel.

How have I obtained such an array ? More or less in the same vein as for Dobble, by using finite fields. More precisely  by considering *planes* (instead of lines for Dobble) in an adequate finite 3D **space** with affine equations

$$ax+by+cy=d,$$

(completely defined by their "normal" vector $(a,b,c)$ and value $d$)

Indeed, as it is the case for 3D affine space $\mathbb{R^3}$, the intersection of 3 affine planes whose normal vectors are independent is reduced to a point.

Here is such an explicit set of cards using (in the background) finite field $\mathbb{F_5}$ (recall : Dobble is based on finite field $\mathbb{F_7}$) :

```
 Plane 1: 1   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   1  
 Plane 2: 1   1   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   0
 Plane 3: 1   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   1
 Plane 4: 1   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0
 Plane 5: 0   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   0
 Plane 6: 0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   1
```

where each of the eleven columns represents a point in the finite three-dimensional vector space $(\mathbb{F_5})^3$, which has $5^3=125$ points.

(boolean value $1$ represents the fact that a certain point belongs to a certain plane).

Said otherwise, if we take as symbols the first 11 letters of the roman alphabet, the "cards" will be :

$$\begin{array}{l}
ACEFHK\\ABDGHJ\\AEGIJK\\ABCDFI\\BEFHIJ\\CDGHIK\end{array}$$

**Remark :** one can observe that, in the previous array, 8 columns have three "$1$"s (like in the first array) but three of them have four "$1$"s : with each of these three columns, one can generate 4 groups of $3$. If we totalize, one gets $8+3 \times 4=20$ : we find back the number of columns of the first array.

I could give details, but I am awaiting you, Sohei, to react to my proposal. I insist on the fact that one of the main issue in the ratio "number of cards vs. number of symbols" for the game to be "playable"...

Thanks to @Mike Earnest who has recalled me the independence criteria for the normal vectors in order that there is a (unique) solution. It is his remark that make me realize that we can work in an ordinary (non projective) finite vector space.

Comment: See the didactic accpted answer to this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2099192/305862) for the projective space associated with vector space $(\mathbb{F_3})^2$ with its $3^2+3+1$ planes...

Comment: See as well [this reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/463369/305862)

Comment: @Mike Earnest Thanks for your objection ; a remedy is to consider a *(maximal) subset* of planes having 3 by 3 their associated $v_1,v_2,v_3$ independent. I must do explicit calculations for example in the space considered in the references I have given.

Comment: An important keyword for placing your question in a wider context: ["(Combinatorial) Design Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_design)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, 6 symbols each for a 6 card game sounds really promising, does this scale well? If it stays about the same number of symbols on each card as there are cards, that would sound playable.

Comment: An objective that sounds hard to achieve... On your side, which methodology have you used ? Do you have interesting results/observations to share ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general method to construct a Dobble variant deck where any $n$ cards have a unique symbol in common. This generalizes the method used in [Jean Marie's answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4717578/177399)

1. Let $F$ be a finite field. Say that $|F|=q$, so $q$ is a prime power. 
   Let $V=F^{n+1}$.
2. Find a list, $C$, of vectors in $V$, such that any $n$ distinct vectors in $C$ are linearly independent. I call this property "$n$-wise linearly independent." $C$ will be the set of cards.

   - Finding a list of $m$ vectors in $F^{n+1}$ which are $n$-wise independent is equivalent to finding a $[m,m-n-1,n+1]_q$ code. Specifically, given such a code, its parity check matrix is a $(n+1)\times m$ matrix with elements in $F$, and the columns of this matrix will be $n$-wise independent. I learned this from [this MO question and answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/386893/largest-set-of-k-wise-linearly-independent-vectors-in-mathbb-f-qn).
     There is no general method to determine the largest $m$ such that a $[m,m-n-1,n+1]_q$ exists, as far as I know. In practice, you need to consult a database of known codes, such as http://www.codetables.de.
3. Let $S$ be the set of vectors in $V$ whose leftmost nonzero coordinate is equal to $1$. There are $q^n + q^{n-1} + \dots + q + 1$ vectors in $S$. $S$ will be the set of symbols.
4. For each $c\in C$, and each $s\in S$, symbol $s$ appears on card $c\cdot s=0$, where $\cdot$ is the dot product performed with finite field arithmetic.

Given any $n$ cards, with vectors $c_1,\dots,c_n$, we know by assumption that the list of vectors in linearly independent. Therefore, the system of $n$ equations, defined by $c_i\cdot v=0$ for each $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$, has a one-dimensional subspace of solutions. There is a unique representative in this subspace whose first nonzero coordinate is $1$, corresponding to the unique symbol shared by all cards.

##### Example 1

Let $F=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, and let $n=3$. The columns of this $4\times 8$ matrix are three-wise linearly independent. The eight columns are the eight vectors in $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^4$ with an odd number of ones.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0&1&1&1\\
0&1&0&0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&1&1&0&1\\
0&0&0&1&1&1&1&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Following the method described above, here is the resulting Dobble card set produced.  Each binary vector is interpreted as a binary integer between $1$ and $14$ for the representation below. There are $8$ cards, with $7$ symbols per card, using $14$ symbols total. Since $n=3$, any $3$ cards have a unique symbol in common.

```
Card    1:    2    4    6    8   10   12   14 
Card    2:    1    4    5    8    9   12   13 
Card    4:    1    2    3    8    9   10   11 
Card    7:    3    5    6    8   11   13   14 
Card    8:    1    2    3    4    5    6    7 
Card   11:    3    4    7    9   10   13   14 
Card   13:    2    5    7    9   11   12   14 
Card   14:    1    6    7   10   11   12   13
```

##### Example 2

Now, let us construct a set of cards where any $4$ have a unique intersection. We will $F = \mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ as our field, so we need a collection of vectors in $F^5$ which are $4$-wise linearly independent. It turns out that the columns of the parity check matrix for the $[11,6,5]_3$ [ternary Golay code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_Golay_code) serve this purpose. Initially, this produces an $11$ card deck with $40$ symbols per card, spanning a total of $3^4+3^3+3^2+3^1+1=121$ symbols. However, of these symbols, $55$ symbols appear on $3$ or fewer cards. These symbols can be safely deleted from the cards they appear on while preserving the $4$-intersecting property.

Here is the final deck design. There are $11$ cards, with $30$ symbols per card, spanning $66$ symbols total. This would make for a very challenging game!

```
Card #  1
   2,   4,   6,  10,  12,  17,  18,  25,  28,  30,  35,  36,  47,  54,  59
  69,  73,  75,  83,  85,  87,  91,  93,  99, 104, 106, 110, 112, 114, 119

Card #  2
   3,   4,   5,   9,  10,  11,  24,  25,  33,  35,  40,  45,  47,  54,  55
  56,  69,  75,  84,  85,  86,  90,  91,  92, 105, 106, 114, 115, 116, 120

Card #  3
   1,   4,   7,  11,  17,  18,  21,  24,  27,  30,  33,  40,  47,  56,  59
  63,  69,  73,  83,  86,  89,  90,  93,  96, 100, 106, 109, 112, 115, 117

Card #  4
   2,   3,   7,  11,  12,  20,  21,  25,  27,  35,  36,  40,  45,  55,  59
  60,  69,  73,  82,  86,  87,  91,  96, 100, 104, 105, 108, 112, 116, 118

Card #  5
   1,   5,   6,   9,  17,  20,  21,  25,  28,  33,  36,  40,  47,  55,  59
  60,  63,  75,  81,  85,  89,  92,  93, 100, 104, 105, 110, 111, 115, 118

Card #  6
   0,   5,   7,  10,  12,  17,  20,  24,  28,  30,  35,  40,  45,  56,  60
  63,  73,  75,  82,  84,  89,  92,  96,  99, 104, 106, 109, 111, 116, 119

Card #  7
  81,  82,  83,  84,  85,  86,  87,  89,  90,  91,  92,  93,  96,  99, 100
 104, 105, 106, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120

Card #  8
   0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   9,  10,  11,  12,  17,  18,  20
  21,  24,  25, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120

Card #  9
   0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,  27,  28,  30,  33,  35,  54,  55
  56,  59,  60,  81,  82,  83,  84,  85,  86,  87,  89, 117, 118, 119, 120

Card # 10
   0,   1,   2,   9,  10,  11,  18,  20,  27,  28,  36,  45,  47,  54,  55
  56,  63,  73,  81,  82,  83,  90,  91,  92,  99, 100, 108, 109, 110, 120

Card # 11
   0,   3,   6,   9,  12,  18,  21,  24,  27,  30,  33,  36,  45,  54,  60
  63,  69,  75,  81,  84,  87,  90,  93,  96,  99, 105, 108, 111, 114, 117
```

##### Example 3

This example is again for $n=3$ cards at a time. There are $26$ cards, with $30$ symbols per card, spanning $130$ symbols, where any three cards have a unique symbol in common. Each symbol is an integer between $0$ and $155$, but there are $26$ numbers in that range which do not appear on any cards. Every symbol which is used appears $6$ cards.

The field I used is $\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z$. The $3$-wise linearly independent set of vectors comes from the columns of the parity-check matrix for the $[26,22,4]_5$ code described at http://www.codetables.de/BKLC/BKLC.php?q=5&n=26&k=22.

```
Card # 1 :
   3,   6,  14,  17,  20,  25,  33,  36,  44,  47,  52,  55,  63,  66,  79
  82,  85,  93,  96, 101, 109, 112, 115, 123, 127, 130, 138, 141, 149, 153

Card # 2 :
   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  35,  36,  37,  38,  65,  66,  67,  68,  69,  95
  96,  97,  98,  99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 155

Card # 3 :
   0,   6,  12,  18,  24,  26,  32,  38,  44,  45,  52,  58,  65,  71,  78
  84,  85,  91,  97, 104, 105, 111, 117, 123, 126, 132, 138, 144, 145, 151

Card # 4 :
   2,   7,  12,  17,  22,  25,  30,  35,  40,  45,  53,  58,  63,  68,  73
  76,  86,  91,  96, 104, 109, 114, 119, 124, 128, 133, 138, 143, 148, 150

Card # 5 :
   3,   7,  11,  15,  24,  29,  33,  37,  45,  50,  59,  63,  67,  71,  76
  80,  89,  93,  97, 102, 106, 110, 119, 123, 126, 130, 139, 143, 147, 154

Card # 6 :
   1,   6,  11,  16,  21,  27,  32,  37,  42,  47,  53,  58,  63,  68,  73
  79,  84,  89,  99, 100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 126, 131, 136, 141, 146, 150

Card # 7 :
   3,   8,  13,  18,  23,  27,  32,  37,  42,  47,  51,  61,  66,  71,  75
  80,  85,  90,  95, 104, 109, 114, 119, 124, 129, 134, 139, 144, 149, 150

Card # 8 :
   3,   9,  10,  16,  22,  26,  32,  38,  44,  45,  54,  55,  61,  67,  73
  77,  89,  90,  96, 100, 106, 112, 118, 124, 128, 134, 135, 141, 147, 151

Card # 9 :
   2,   8,  14,  15,  21,  29,  30,  36,  42,  48,  51,  63,  69,  70,  78
  84,  85,  91,  97, 100, 106, 112, 118, 124, 127, 133, 139, 140, 146, 151

Card # 10 :
   2,   5,  13,  16,  24,  26,  34,  37,  40,  48,  50,  58,  61,  69,  79
  82,  85,  93,  96, 103, 106, 114, 117, 120, 129, 132, 135, 143, 146, 153

Card # 11 :
  10,  11,  12,  13,  14,  30,  31,  32,  33,  34,  50,  51,  52,  53,  54
  95,  96,  97,  98,  99, 115, 117, 118, 119, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 155

Card # 12 :
   0,   9,  13,  17,  21,  27,  31,  35,  44,  48,  54,  58,  62,  66,  70
  76,  80,  89,  93,  97, 103, 111, 115, 124, 127, 131, 135, 144, 148, 154

Card # 13 :
   1,   5,  14,  18,  22,  25,  34,  38,  42,  54,  58,  62,  66,  70,  78
  82,  86,  90,  99, 102, 106, 110, 119, 123, 129, 133, 137, 141, 145, 154

Card # 14 :
   1,   8,  10,  17,  24,  29,  31,  38,  40,  47,  52,  59,  61,  68,  70
  75,  82,  89,  91,  98, 103, 105, 112, 119, 128, 130, 137, 144, 146, 152

Card # 15 :
   4,   6,  13,  15,  22,  26,  33,  35,  42,  53,  55,  62,  69,  71,  75
  82,  89,  91,  98, 102, 109, 111, 118, 120, 127, 134, 136, 143, 145, 152

Card # 16 :
   4,   5,  11,  17,  23,  29,  30,  36,  42,  48,  54,  55,  61,  67,  73
  79,  80,  86,  98, 104, 105, 111, 117, 123, 125, 131, 137, 143, 149, 151

Card # 17 :
   2,   9,  11,  18,  20,  27,  34,  36,  45,  52,  59,  61,  68,  70,  77
  84,  86,  93,  95, 102, 109, 111, 118, 120, 125, 132, 139, 141, 148, 152

Card # 18 :
   4,   8,  12,  16,  20,  27,  31,  35,  44,  48,  50,  59,  63,  67,  71
  78,  82,  86,  90,  99, 101, 105, 114, 118, 128, 132, 136, 140, 149, 154

Card # 19 :
   1,   9,  12,  15,  23,  26,  34,  37,  40,  48,  51,  59,  62,  65,  73
  76,  84,  90,  98, 101, 109, 112, 115, 123, 125, 133, 136, 144, 147, 153

Card # 20 :
  20,  21,  22,  23,  24,  30,  31,  32,  33,  34,  65,  66,  67,  68,  69
  75,  76,  77,  78,  79, 110, 111, 112, 114, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 155

Card # 21 :
   0,   7,  14,  16,  23,  29,  31,  38,  40,  47,  53,  55,  62,  69,  71
  77,  84,  86,  93,  95, 101, 110, 117, 124, 129, 131, 138, 140, 147, 152

Card # 22 :
   4,   7,  10,  18,  21,  25,  33,  36,  44,  47,  51,  59,  62,  65,  73
  77,  80,  91,  99, 103, 106, 114, 117, 120, 126, 134, 137, 140, 148, 153

Card # 23 :
 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139
 140, 141, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155

Card # 24 :
   0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12,  13,  14
  15,  16,  17,  18,  20,  21,  22,  23,  24, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155

Card # 25 :
   0,   1,   2,   3,   4,  25,  26,  27,  29,  50,  51,  52,  53,  54,  75
  76,  77,  78,  79, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 155

Card # 26 :
   0,   5,  10,  15,  20,  25,  30,  35,  40,  45,  50,  55,  65,  70,  75
  80,  85,  90,  95, 100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 130, 135, 140, 145, 150
```

Comment: [+1] Analysis in depth. Very interesting.